# How to calculate price depending the room type and check in-out dates

Tags: javascript

A costumer needs to rent a room

i need a easy way to calculate the total price
depending the check in, check out dates and the type of the room

two rooms, the one cheap the other one expensive
the price changes every month (only 4 summer months)

```
Room 1 
price 10 euro per day (june) 
price 20 euro per day (july) 
price 30 euro per day (August)  
price 15 euro per day (September) 
                    
Room 2
price 20 euro per day (june) 
price 30 euro per day (july) 
price 50 euro per day (August)  
price 25 euro per day (September)
```

How it is possible to calculate it?

Using Java, php, SQL ??????

```html
<select name="room" id="room">
  <option value="">Select Room</option>
  <option>Room 1</option>
  <option>Room 2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="checkin" name="checkin">

<input type="text" id="checkout" name="checkout">

<input type="number" id="Totalamount" name="Totalamount">
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck when you tried this yourself? And what language would you prefer to work in, since you've mentioned [tag:java], [tag:php] and [tag:sql], but tagged the question with [tag:javascript], which isn't mentioned (and JavaScript **is not** related to Java).

Comment: [How do I ask a homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as my opinion you have to save each day price for each room
Room1, june01 => 10euro
Room1, june02 => 10euro
...
after that you can get checkin and checkout for each room and calculate the total price

checkIn june01 checkOut june05 => total price for room1 for 5 days is (room1-june01 price + room1-june02 price + room1-june03 price + room1-june04 price + room1-june05 price)

in this case it will be 50 euro